# is tdengine support json type and how to use that?

Tags: tdengine

I use using tnenginge, but i meet a problem is that we have lots of json data. I know mysql supports json type. I want to ask does tdengine support json type. since there are a mounts of data need to be stored and exact data from json is very expensive. Does any one know that will or is  tdengine supports the json type?
How to use that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes, I can find json type in TDengine's document.
[image]